# Vector icon as button content inside style not display in design time

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to use vector icon as content inside Button style to use in multiple buttons (more than 20). So, I did like this:

**my icon:**

```
<Rectangle x:Key="DefaultsIcon" Height="20" Width="20" x:Shared="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
                    <Path Width="29.26" Height="32.5111" Canvas.Left="24.9269" Canvas.Top="21.3222" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 24.9269,53.8333L 24.9269,21.3222L 36.6106,21.3222C 48.3282,21.3222 54.1869,26.6053 54.1869,37.1714C 54.1869,42.2319 52.588,46.274 49.3901,49.2977C 46.1922,52.3215 41.9324,53.8333 36.6106,53.8333L 24.9269,53.8333 Z M 32.3581,27.36L 32.3581,47.7956L 36.0156,47.7956C 39.2231,47.7956 41.7377,46.8509 43.5591,44.9617C 45.3806,43.0725 46.2914,40.5023 46.2914,37.2512C 46.2914,34.1791 45.3879,31.7625 43.5809,30.0015C 41.7739,28.2405 39.2376,27.36 35.972,27.36L 32.3581,27.36 Z "/>
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

**my style:**

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource CameraButtonBaseStyle}" x:Key="CameraDefaultsButtonStyle">
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource CameraUISettings}, Path=OptionLBMargin, Mode=OneWay, Converter={uiConverters:DoubleToLeftMarginConverter}}"></Setter>
     <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource CameraLocalization}, Path=ToolTips.Default, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
     <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultsIcon}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

**and apply style:**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource CameraDefaultsButtonStyle}"  
                                 Click="LoadDefaultX_OnClick">
</Button>
```

But the problem here is that in design time only 1 icon of all displaying and in runtime all icons displaying good. I want that in design time icons also were visible. 
How to reach this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `DefaultsIcon` style contains a visual. The style is created only once per lifetime of your app and reused as often as needed. But a visual can only be used once in the visual tree. A quick fix is to add `x:Shared="Falsed"` to `DefaultsIcon`. From the architectural perspective that's not the best solution because now for every usage of `DefaultsIcon` a new instance is created.

Comment: I have already set x:Shared="Falsed", but it doesnt help. What is the best solution here?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, just add `x:Shared="Falsed"` to your `Button` style.

Comment: The same result - in designer vector icons still doesn show, but in runtime everything OK. Is there another solution which will let me to see vector icons in design time?

Comment: Indeed, now I get the same (wrong) result after I restarted Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Because I want to share some code I add a new answer. My question is do you need the `DefaultsIcon` style somewhere else? If not you could do the following to get the same result:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="CameraDefaultsButtonStyle" x:Shared="False" >
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="hello"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Path Width="29.26" Height="32.5111" Canvas.Left="24.9269" Canvas.Top="21.3222" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black" Data="F1 M 24.9269,53.8333L 24.9269,21.3222L 36.6106,21.3222C 48.3282,21.3222 54.1869,26.6053 54.1869,37.1714C 54.1869,42.2319 52.588,46.274 49.3901,49.2977C 46.1922,52.3215 41.9324,53.8333 36.6106,53.8333L 24.9269,53.8333 Z M 32.3581,27.36L 32.3581,47.7956L 36.0156,47.7956C 39.2231,47.7956 41.7377,46.8509 43.5591,44.9617C 45.3806,43.0725 46.2914,40.5023 46.2914,37.2512C 46.2914,34.1791 45.3879,31.7625 43.5809,30.0015C 41.7739,28.2405 39.2376,27.36 35.972,27.36L 32.3581,27.36 Z "/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The need to set `x:Shared="False"` is for me a sign to think of a small user control instead of a style.

Comment: So, if I add inside Content my own usercontrol, there is no need for x:Shared="False"?

Answer (score 0):

No, I mean a mini user control as a replacement for your `CameraDefaultsButtonStyle` style, not only the Content within that style. The control could look like this:

```
<Button x:Class="TabControl1.CameraDefaultsButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             ToolTip="Hello">
    <Grid>
        <Path Width="29.26" Height="32.5111" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black" Data="F1 M 24.9269,53.8333L 24.9269,21.3222L 36.6106,21.3222C 48.3282,21.3222 54.1869,26.6053 54.1869,37.1714C 54.1869,42.2319 52.588,46.274 49.3901,49.2977C 46.1922,52.3215 41.9324,53.8333 36.6106,53.8333L 24.9269,53.8333 Z M 32.3581,27.36L 32.3581,47.7956L 36.0156,47.7956C 39.2231,47.7956 41.7377,46.8509 43.5591,44.9617C 45.3806,43.0725 46.2914,40.5023 46.2914,37.2512C 46.2914,34.1791 45.3879,31.7625 43.5809,30.0015C 41.7739,28.2405 39.2376,27.36 35.972,27.36L 32.3581,27.36 Z "/>
    </Grid>
</Button>

using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TabControl1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CameraDefaultsButton.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CameraDefaultsButton : Button
    {
        public CameraDefaultsButton ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

You use it this way like the standard button:

```
<Window x:Class="TabControl1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControl1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <local:CameraDefaultsButton Margin="301,164,0,0" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                Width="139" 
                                Height="55"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <local:CameraDefaultsButton Margin="301,236,0,0" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Width="139" 
                                Height="55"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

but don't forget to add the namespace where you use it:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControl1"
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but I think it must be something more flexible, because I have not only one style) I think I need to inherit from contentpresenter class and use content property to add icon to control (not hardcode). Something like that. Hope that will work without making Share=False.